# if statement doesn't run when I use a function even if the conditions are met

Tags: python, if-statement

If statements in my function named ConvertFile are not running even if the conditions are met.

```
def errorHandle(file: str) -> list:
        with open(file) as f:
            FileRead = re.split('["\n]', f.read())
            commands = ["print"]
            for line in FileRead:
                line = line.split('"')
                func = line[0]
                if func in commands:
                    FileRead.remove(FileRead[FileRead.index(line)])
        return FileRead
def convertFile(ConvertFile: str):
    if not ConvertFile.split(".")[1] == 'mar':
        raise WrongFileExtensionException()
    with open(ConvertFile, 'r') as File:
        name: list = re.split("[/.]", ConvertFile)
        FileRead: list = errorHandle(ConvertFile)
        for lineIndex in range(len(FileRead)):
            line: str = FileRead[lineIndex]
            lineSplitted: list = line.split('"')
            func: str = lineSplitted[0].lower()
            if func == "print":
                print("TRUE")
        with open(f"{name[1]}.py", "w") as Converted:
            Converted.writelines(FileRead)
```

If I add `print(func)` after the `func` declarement, it will return

```
print
hello world
```

Comment: This is very unusual:  `if not ConvertFile.split(".")[1] == 'mar':`  Wouldn't it be clearer to write `if ConvertFile.split(".")[1] != 'mar':` ?

Comment: `print("func:", func, "length:", len(func))` and see what it says. I'm guessing there's whitespace you're not accounting for.

Comment: @TomKarzes I actually didn't know that '!=' was in python.

Comment: @GuyIncognito It had a whitespace at the end of print. I added a check to remove space in the ```func``` variable.

Comment: @Panda Python has the usual comparison operators:  `==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`.  It has some others as well, like `is`, `is not`, etc.